# Why is my Google Chrome New Tab saying Webpage Not Found

Tags: google-chrome, performance, browser-tabs

My Google Chrome New Tab won't work it says "webpage not found" ? Why is it doing this I've went to the settings & checked that i just don't kniw why it won't work i need help with this really badly

Comment: Is the site reachable in another browser? Like Firefox, Opera, Internet Explorer.
Is this website your own website? If not, what is the URL? We need much more information before we can answer this question.

Comment: No its not an website if you use google chrome when you open a new window it says New tab on it but mine says "Webpage Not Found"

Answer (score 2):

It is probably caused by an extention, try removing extentions one at a time.

First of all to go to `Controlpanel > Add/Remove Programs` and look for a program called "Default Tab", if it's their, remove it. This program gets installed when installing certain other programs and it's just their to be annoying.

You could go to `Settings -> Tools -> Extentions` and delete from their, but some extention might start again when restarting Google Chrome.

So another way of doing it is:

- Go to run or press Win + R
- Copy/paste this in to it: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\\Default\Extensions` (Windows 7/8) and press enter
- Delete the folders their to delete the extentions

**EDIT**
Sorry, got the original path mixed up, should be fixed now.

Comment: You probably could use %appdata% instead of C:\Users\jj\AppData\ where jj is the current username

Comment: doh, thanks for noticing. Originally I did copy the path with %LOCALDATA%, but I somehow got it mixed up again :)

Comment: @Kamryn Agree with Jesper Jensen, Close it ASAP. I was thinking about your question then I saw you wrote `it works now` SO close it !

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Google Chrome settings and there should be a section titled "On Startup" for you to change.

For instance, mine said "Open the new tab page which is being controlled by 'television'" it was some sort of web page controlling what happens when I open a new tab/window.

This is what fixed my situation.